# Usage of nouns and adjectives

Tags: nouns, adjectives

When do you say: "noun's noun", "noun of noun", "noun + noun" and "adjective + noun"?

For example there's an album called "demon days" by Gorillaz.  I think demonic is right, because demonic(adj) describes the noun. Or maybe 'these are the days of the demon'?

Answer (score 1):

**Fish tank** is an example of a [compound](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/word-formation/compounds) noun.

Sometimes compound nouns use the *closed form*, e.g. baseball, earphones.

*Demon Days* is an example of an *open form*.

Hyphens are also common, e.g. fire-fighter.

You can make compounds in all word classes, not just nouns.  See the provided link.